# Specific radius for every point in Highchart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

We want set specific radius for every point in chart, how to do this with Highchart?
We have code something like this:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    margin: 100,
    type: 'scatter3d',
    options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 10,
        beta: 30,
        depth: 250,
        viewDistance: 5,
        fitToPlot: false,
        frame: {
            bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
            back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
            side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
        }
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Draggable box'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Click and drag the plot area to rotate in space'
},
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        depth: 10,
    },
    series:{
        marker:{
            radius: [5,10,20]
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    title: null
},
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    gridLineWidth: 1
},
zAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    showFirstLabel: false
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [{
    name: 'Reading',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [[1, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4]],
    colors: ['#0d233a', '#0d233a', '#0d233a']
}]
});
```

if it's possible to use array of radiuses in plotOptions.series.marker.radius?
If there is another method can be used to set radius for every point in chart!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different marker sizes in highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870308/different-marker-sizes-in-highcharts)

Comment: yes! thank you. now work fine!.