# How to dynamically alter Highcharts radius option for a specific user?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am creating an scattered highchart. Each scatter point in this highchart represents a user, now what I want to do is the size(radius)of the loggedin user should be more than that of other users. So all the scatter points will be of one size and the scatter point of logged in user will be of another size. I want to alter the radius of only that scatter point that represents the loggedin user to 7.5.

First I will have to find out which one is my loggedin user and then I will have to change the radius of that scatter point, I beleive inside an If condition we cannot change the radius.

P.S. All my data is coming from a single series.

```
    plotOptions: {
                                scatter: {
                                    marker: {
                                        radius: 3.5,
                                        states: {
                                            hover: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                lineColor: 
                                                'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                            }
                                        }


One of the things that I tried is:
point: {
      events: {
            load:  function(){
                if (this.tempName == currObj.loggedInUser) {                                                     
                    this.series.update({marker:{radius:7.5}});
                }
            }
    }                                            
  }
```

But this gives an error  : ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'radius' of undefined

my series data is coming from database. Is it possible to do this?
All my data is coming from a single series.

```
data: [{name: "", x: 27748468.3, y: 108.76, noOfParts: "19"},…]
0
:
{name: "", x: 27748468.3, y: 108.76, noOfParts: "19"}
1
:
{name: "", x: 9562580, y: 123.82, noOfParts: "7"}
2
:
{name: "", x: 5299808.8, y: 88.92, noOfParts: "3"}
3
:
{name: "", x: 5461182.2, y: 120.93, noOfParts: "9"}
4
:
:
{name: "", x: 125913281.3, y: 112.61, noOfParts: "29"}
5
:
{name: "", x: 116723983.3, y: 110.4, noOfParts: "36"}
6
:
{name: "", x: 48781718.3, y: 116.97, noOfParts: "15"}
7
:
{name: "", x: 15208335, y: 106.24, noOfParts: "7"}
8
:
{name: "", x: 78205149.3, y: 115.51, noOfParts: "47"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different marker sizes in highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870308/different-marker-sizes-in-highcharts)

Comment: if requirement is like this you not you make two series in javascript and then pass to the highcharts

Comment: so it is not possible to do it in a single series? Making two different series will require a lot of effort as same chart is being used dynamically in multiple places and I am already running short of time.

Comment: can you add sample of the series which you get from server side. If it is possible then processing  will increase

Comment: sample series added. I was also thinking will it be possible if I send marker size for each user from backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`marker.radius` can be assigned to individual points too (in your example you're setting it only on series).

Iterate your points before passing them to Highcharts and set `marker.radius` for the desired point:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: 5,
      y: 6,
      marker: {
        radius: 10
      }
    },
      (...)
    ]
  }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h09s9pm3/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.data.marker.radius